# how to view sqlite database in xamarin

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, xamarin

I'm working with Xamarin Studio to do a iPad App using sqlite database.
How can I see the table I created and the data in it ?

I tried using Firefox sqlite add in, but couldn't find the database file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the Simulator files from `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/`.

In this folder are the various iOS version numbers so pick the one you are running. In that will be `Applications` and you'll see a bunch of GUIDs, one of which will be the running app. And then you can easily find your sqlite database file.